# The error shows it does not take an argument. How to make this right?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game and an error pops up continuously that I don't know how to solve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/GROOT!/new start.py", line 46, in <module>
    man = player(300, 410, 64, 64)
TypeError: player() takes no arguments
```

This is the error. And the code is below:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Game//R1.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R2.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R3.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R4.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R5.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R6.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R7.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R8.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Game//L1.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L2.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L3.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L4.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L5.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L6.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L7.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L8.png'), pygame.image.load('Game//L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('Game//bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('Game//standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player(object):
    def __init_(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isjump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
        
    if left:  
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (int(x),int(y)))
        walkCount += 1                          
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (int(x),int(y)))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (int(x), int(y)))
        walkCount = 0
        
    pygame.display.update() 
    
man = player(300, 410, 64, 64)
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > man.vel: 
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.vel - man.width:  
        man.x += vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = True
        
    else: 
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
        man.walkCount = 0
        
    if not(man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.left = False
            man.right = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount * abs(man.jumpCount)) * 0.5
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else: 
            man.jumpCount = 10
            man.isJump = False

    redrawGameWindow() 
    
    
pygame.quit()
```

I wrote the whole code because I don't exactly know which part of it is wrong. The only information I got from the error is that player() does not take any argument. I even defined it above in the class() but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `def __init_` needs to be `def __init__` (note the underscores). Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate I'll just delete this question

Comment: Now that there's a answer, that's a bad idea. You can be question banned for that. The answerer really shouldn't have answered this though unfortunately, since it is just a simple typo.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes now I'll not delete it but be more careful next time before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `def __init_` to `def __init__` (double underscores at the end instead of a single underscore)